# Record sound from microphone using NAudio. Why not works correctly record the whole buffer from the list?

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording, naudio

Good time of day. Please tell me why the code No. 2 is not quite functioning correctly? When playing the recorded file you hear only sounds like clicks. Although code No. 1 (works fine), it differs only in that the buffer is not immediately written to the file, and is added to the list, and then after recording the entire buffer from the list is written to the file.

№1

```
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace Record
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        WaveIn waveIn;
        WaveFileWriter waveWriter;


        private void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveWriter == null) return;

            waveWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            waveWriter.Flush();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            waveIn = new WaveIn();
            waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
            string outputFilename = @"D:/demo.wav";
            waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveIn.DeviceNumber).Channels);

            waveIn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveIn_DataAvailable);
            waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveIn.WaveFormat);
            waveIn.StartRecording();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (waveIn != null)
            {
                waveIn.StopRecording();
                waveIn.Dispose();
                waveIn = null;
            }
            if (waveWriter != null)
            {
                waveWriter.Dispose();
                waveWriter = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

№2

```
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace RecordReally
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        WaveIn waveIn;
        WaveFileWriter waveWriter;
        string outputFilename = @"D:/demo.wav";
        List<byte[]> bytes = new List<byte[]>();

        private void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        { 
            bytes.Add(e.Buffer);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            waveIn = new WaveIn();
            waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
            waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveIn.DeviceNumber).Channels);
            waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveIn.WaveFormat);
            waveIn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveIn_DataAvailable);
            waveIn.StartRecording();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (waveIn != null)
            {
                waveIn.StopRecording();
                waveIn.Dispose();
                waveIn = null;
            }
            foreach (byte[] buffer in bytes)
            {
                waveWriter.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                waveWriter.Flush();
            }
            if (waveWriter != null)
            {
                waveWriter.Dispose();
                waveWriter = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `bytes.Add(e.Buffer);` does not copy the bytes. You need to create a new array and copy the data to the new array, then add the new array to the list.

Comment: Thank you! Works)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] ebuffer = new byte[e.BytesRecorded];
    for (int n = 0; n < ebuffer.Length; n++)
    {
        ebuffer[n] = e.Buffer[n];
    }
    bytes.Add(ebuffer);
}
```

Comment: Please add details that explain how this would work or what it does, which would make it easier to understand.